# User specific sonar reports for same project

Tags: sonarqube

I have configured one project in sonar and integrated sonar with maven for build time analysis of the project.

After analysis, report is generated and uploaded to Sonar for browsing. But once another user compiles the same project their report overwrites mine.

Basically I want that one user's report on one project is not overwritten by report from other user. A user must be able to see their current violations independently. Is it possible in Sonar?

Answer (score 4):

Sonar stores it's analysis on a daily basis, which explains why it's kind of pointless to run analysis several times in a day. Each analysis run will overwrite that day's existing results, which in turn spoils ongoing statistical analysis.

I would suggest running Sonar, from a dedicated build server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (which has a Sonar plug-in). This daily analysis will populate the Sonar database and keep the project dashboard current. This architecture also enables you to keep the database credentials confidential.

Obviously developers would like to see the results of their bug fixing. For that I'd recommend running the Sonar Eclipse plug-in. The latest version will run the same Sonar analysis locally. Recent versions of Sonar also enable you to assign violations to developers for resolution.

Comment: +1 - just wasted hours trying to find how to delete an analysis done today... only to find out that the analysis kicked off later had already deleted the bad one for me. Thanks to your post I can stop searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, last performed analysis will always be the one you browse in the interface. However, I guess what you need is the [Issue Report Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin) which will enable analysis to store results locally, with the *dry-run* option.

This way your developers will be able to run an analysis on their code and see the violation delta without pushing the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by explicitly setting the below properties in pom.xml

```
<properties>
            <sonar.projectKey>Test</sonar.projectKey>
             <sonar.projectName>Test</sonar.projectName>
</properties>
```

Every user should set **different projectKey and projectName**, if you want that one user's report on one project is not overwritten by report from other user.